# if two collectionviews in one controller sizeForItemAtIndexPath does not work

Tags: ios

I have two collectionViews in one controller, cellForItemAtIndexPath works fine with the below code

```
if(collectionView == collectionview1){
}
else
{}
```

But it does not work for the below method

```
(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use different tags, say 1 and 2 for the two collectionviews.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     if(collectionView.tag == 1){
         //do stuffs related to the first collectionView
     }else{
         //do stuffs related to the first collectionView
     }
}
```